# Powershell stop script if it not running as admin

Tags: powershell

I got a script I'm using when I install a new laptop.

Sometimes I forget to run it as admin.

Is it possible to stop the script and show a message box if it's not running as admin?

Answer (score 1):

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```

This retrieves the current windows identity and returns True if the current identity has the Administrator role (i.e., running elevated).

From there you could wrap it in an if -not block and present a message box, like so:

```
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Not running as administrator!");
}
```

Note: This is based on this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/756696

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Travis is decent, but I found the message box thing did not work for me, it threw an error. Here is a similar solution but it uses the standard `Write-Host` and also makes the text color red:

```
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Write-Host("Not running as administrator! Please run PowerShell as admin.") -ForegroundColor Red;
    exit;
}
```